# Keep values assigned to one column in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with three columns:

```
Name Customer Value
Johnny Mike     1
Christopher Luke 0
Christopher Mike 0
Carl        Marilyn 1
Carl        Stephen 1
```

I need to create a new dataset where I have two columns: one with unique values from `Name` and `Customer` columns, and the `Value` column. Values in the `Value` column were assigned to `Name` (this means that multiple rows with same `Name` have the same value: Carl has value 1, Christopher has value 0, and Johnny has value 1), so `Customer` elements should have empty values in `Value` column in the new dataset.
My expected output is

```
All        Value
Johnny       1
Christopher  0
Carl         1
Mike
Luke
Marilyn
Stephen
```

For unique values in `All` column I consider `unique().to_list()` from both `Name` and `Customer`:

```
name = file['Name'].unique().tolist()
customer = file['Customer'].unique().tolist()
all_with_dupl = name + customer
customers=list(dict.fromkeys(all_with_dupl))

df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['All','Value'])
df['All']= customers
```

I do not know how to assign the values in the new dataset after creating the list with all names and customers with no duplicates.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split columns and `.drop_duplicates` on data frame to remove duplicates and then `append` it back:

```
(df.drop('Customer', 1)
   .drop_duplicates()
   .rename(columns={'Name': 'All'})
   .append(
     df[['Customer']].rename(columns={'Customer': 'All'})
       .drop_duplicates(),
     ignore_index=True
   ))

           All  Value
0       Johnny    1.0
1  Christopher    0.0
2         Carl    1.0
3         Mike    NaN
4         Luke    NaN
5      Marilyn    NaN
6      Stephen    NaN
```

Or to split the steps up:

```
names = df.drop('Customer', 1).drop_duplicates().rename(columns={'Name': 'All'})
customers = df[['Customer']].drop_duplicates().rename(columns={'Customer': 'All'})
names.append(customers, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Anaother way

```
 d=dict(zip(df['Name Customer'].str.split('\s').str[0],df['Value']))#Create dict
    df['Name Customer']=df['Name Customer'].str.split('\s')
    df=df.explode('Name Customer').drop_duplicates(keep='first').assign(Value='')Explode dataframe and drop duplicates
    df['Value']=df['Name Customer'].map(d).fillna('')#Map values back
```